# Knock Sensor using 555 Timer with a timed light

Tags: sensor, timer, 555

I have seen a few Knock Sensors using the Piezo Speaker and the Arduino. I am wondering if there is a way to eliminate the Arduino and utilize a 555 Timer and other simpler components so that when the Piezo sensor detects a Knock it triggers a Relay to illuminate a light either in three successive pulses lasting 3 seconds or a continuous on time of 3 seconds then off again until the next Knock? ie: (Knock: Blink Blink Blink, or Knock Light on(3 seconds)off) I apologize, I have just started learning some of this.

Comment: Look up 555 or 556 one shot mode

Answer (score 2):

Use a 555 timer as a monostable with a 3 second timeout directly driving an LED, pull the 555's input up to Vcc, and trigger the 555 with a negative-going cap-coupled pulse generated by the piezo loudspeaker and amplified enough to drive the 555's trigger input to lower than Vcc/3.